# I failed to submit the training operation on the AI platform of GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine, gcp-ai-platform-training

I failed to submit the training operation on the AI platform of GCP.The error is "xxx@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to your-bucket-name/fcnndemo/trainer/packages/980a4aa0a09719cf43f04580d8e6c218346e3ad085e3f48fd11b79ec57a702fe/ai_platform_demo-0.0.0.tar.gz."

I am trying to use the data in GEE and submit it to the AI platform for training.I'm running it on a Colab notebook.

```
import time

# INSERT YOUR PROJECT HERE!
PROJECT = 'your-project'

JOB_NAME = 'demo_training_job_' + str(int(time.time()))
TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH = 'ai_platform_demo'
MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE = 'ai_platform_demo.task'
REGION = 'us-central1'

!gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training {JOB_NAME} \
    --job-dir {config.JOB_DIR}  \
    --package-path {TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH} \
    --module-name {MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE} \
    --region {REGION} \
    --project {PROJECT} \
    --runtime-version 1.14 \
    --python-version 3.5 \
    --scale-tier basic-gpu
```

why do not I have  storage.objects.create access?

Comment: Do you know your current role? Your current connected user? Perform this command `!gcloud config list` to know more about this. We agree that you changed the values (`your-bucket-name` and `your-project`) only for this post, but in reality, these values are correct and you can access to these resources?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have storage.objects.create permissions you need to grant it to your user using Cloud IAM permissions. In [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) you will find instructions on how to control who has access to your buckets and objects.

In order to test it out I have successfully submitted a training job from Google Colab following [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-keras). Make sure to login with your user with the command '!gcloud auth login'.

The code I have used is the following:

```
!gcloud auth login
BUCKET_NAME=’<<YOUR_BUCKET>>’
REGION='europe-west1'
JOB_NAME='test_job'
JOB_DIR='gs://<<YOUR_BUCKET>>/keras-job-dir'

!git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples
!cd cloudml-samples/census/tf-keras/ && ls -pR && pip install -r requirements.txt


!gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
  --package-path cloudml-samples/census/tf-keras/trainer/ \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --region {REGION} \
  --python-version 3.5 \
  --runtime-version 1.13 \
  --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
  --stream-logs
```

---